# MethodInvoker lost?

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is my code:

```
private void TaskGestioneCartelle()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GeneraListaCartelle())
        .ContinueWith(t => GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void GeneraListaCartelle()
{
    // ... code
}

private void GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CopiaCartelle())
        .ContinueWith(t => CopiaCartelleCompletato()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void CopiaCartelle()
{
    if (txtLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtLog.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { txtLog.AppendText("Copio cartelle in corso..." + Environment.NewLine); }));
    }
}
```

It start a Thread. When finish, I start another thread (from the Continue with) and I try to write somethings in a Control on the UI. But in fact nothing is written on `txtLog`. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I try to write somethings in a Control on the UI. But in fact nothing
>   is written on txtLog. Where am I wrong?

Because at that time, Invoke is Not Required. You can modify your if statement and add an `else` part which would do the same.

```
private void CopiaCartelle()
{
    if (txtLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtLog.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { txtLog.AppendText("Copio cartelle in corso..." + Environment.NewLine); }));
    }
    else // this part when Invoke is not required. 
    {
     txtLog.AppendText("Copio cartelle in corso..." + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

You can refactor the text append path to a method and call it that method from `if-else`

Comment: I think removing `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());` (for experiments sake) would make the current code work, right?

Comment: @ByteBlast, may be, not sure, but OP can try

Comment: So when is that InvokeRequired is required? I'm in a Thread, it should must be required :O

Comment: @paizza, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

Comment: I think there I'm not in a thread, also because the UI is frozen, uhm... why? I mean, `CopiaCartelle` shouldn't freeze the UI...

Comment: Did you see? Or maybe I open a new topic?

Comment: @paizza, just saw it now, I don't think this much work should freez the UI, but I guess its only a sample, May be it has to do with the options you specified while creating Task, I am not entirely sure about it. You can ask a new question or wait and see if somebody else replies to this post.